# Get content of <use> svg using Snap.vg

Tags: svg

I would like to ask can you select the content of the svg element that's being addressed by `<use>` with Snap.svg, and if yes how do you do it.

**SVG file content**

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 

    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" x="0px" y="0px" xml:space="preserve">
     <g id="contacts_mail_icon">
            <path d="M7,7L5.268,5.484L0.316,9.729C0.496,9.896,0.739,10,1.007,10h11.986c0.267,0,0.509-0.104,0.688-0.271L8.732,5.484L7,7z"/>
            <path d="M13.684,0.271C13.504,0.103,13.262,0,12.993,0H1.007C0.74,0,0.498,0.104,0.318,0.273L7,6L13.684,0.271z"/>
            <polygon points="0,0.878 0,9.186 4.833,5.079    "/>
            <polygon points="9.167,5.079 14,9.186 14,0.875  "/>
        </g>
    </svg>
```

HTML

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
                                x="0px" y="0px"
                                width="30px" height="30px" viewBox="0 0 14 10" 
                                enable-background="new 0 0 14 10" xml:space="preserve"
                                fill="#6e6e6e"
                                class="do-animate-mail-icon"
                            >
                                <use class="do-animate-mail" xlink:href="path_to_sprite.svg#contacts_mail_icon"></use>
                            </svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had similar thing some days ago.... In fact, the content of a use is shadow dom, or in other words, a link to the content of the element it refers to. The use itself is treated as a group element.

To answer your question: I do not know how to do it with snap.svg, but all you need to do is take the value of the href attribute of the use, therein is the id of the original element, which you can get and access its content.

In your case, you need to load the sprite svg, create a document from it and query this document for the id you are looking for...

**EDIT**

Well probably that helps: The `instanceRoot` property...

http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#InterfaceSVGUseElement

Comment: Thanks for the tip man I was able to do it using $.load by passing the value of the xlink:href attire without the id and then within that link I search for the ID. Sorry that I can't give you a thumbs up for the answer but I don't have the reputation for that, but I've checked your answer as correct :)

Comment: Note that `instanceRoot` (including the entire `SVGElementInstance` interface) has been dropped from SVG2. So, I wouldn't recommend using that as the way to look for particular ids.

Comment: OK, haven't known this… What's the suggested method to access the content?